# c# Selenium 2.53 moving to marionette driver after firefox upgrade to 47

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, firefox-marionette

I am trying to move into the upgraded firefox web browser automation using selenium. It seems that selenium needs marionette driver to continue working. I followed the instructions set by the devs,

1. downloaded the driver
2. renamed it to wires.exe

The following code didnt manage to properly set the PATH to a custom path.

System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.gecko.driver", "@C:\DOWNLOADS\wires.exe")

so i added wires.exe to the debug\bin folder and then wires.exe worked properly but i got the following error

> **System.InvalidOperationException was caught   Message=entity not found   Source=WebDriver**

this is the code i use to start webdriver

```
FirefoxOptions option1 = new FirefoxOptions();
option1.IsMarionette = true;
option1.AddAdditionalCapability("marionette", true);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(option1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too got the ***"Entity Not Found"*** error using FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxOptions()). It appears to be looking for firefox.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Nightly and not finding it. I found this working :

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

Comment: Excellent this works for me but is it possible to create marionette driver as shown above with firefoxprofile? I don't see any option to create driver with service and profile as inputs?

Answer (score 2):

I try with this and it's working:

1. Install FirefoxDevEdition
2. Download geckodriver.exe

---

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Users\jmalpartida\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.8.0-win32", "geckodriver.exe");
service.Port = 64444;
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe";
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add the driver to your system path, not as an env variable. 
Second, you need to set the flag in a desired capability, not a Firefox option. See: [Marionette Webdriver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver)

As such for remote webdriver:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();  
capabilities.SetCapability("marionette", true); 
var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(capabilities);
```

To add the webdriver to your [windows path](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path):

The easiest way is to open the start menu > search for environment > open edit the system environment variables > click on environment variables > search in the list for Path > click on edit > add `;C:\path\to\webdriver\location\wires.exe` to the end and click save.

For your local (non-webdriver) tests you are right, you can run your webdriver using the following:

`var driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxOptions());`

You should not have to use

`option1.IsMarionette = true;
 option1.AddAdditionalCapability("marionette", true);`

If you have set the driver path correctly in your path environment variable.

Comment: do i have to use Remotewebdriver? There is the option to simply upgrade at the site you mentioned "Updating your tests to use Marionette" but only a simple line of code which is similar to the one i used. By the way the driver i downloaded is an exe file which i renamed to the file wires.exe. When u say to add the driver to system path you mean sth like "C:\Windows" am i correct?

Comment: I've tried this, doesn't work, I still get entity not found error