# How do i get selenuim to stop showing this error message?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to do a simple tester script because I wanted to get into it, but when I ran my first script, this happened. I tried installing gecko, but I have no idea how to install it, and all the tutorials didn't work for me. Any help would be much appreciated!

Using visual studio and c#

[image: Error message]

Comment: Here is a relevant solution that maybe you can refer to. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/39426778/8335151](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39426778/8335151)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open firefox driver you need to set gecko driver by path.

```
    //Give the path of the geckodriver.exe    
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.13.0-win64","geckodriver.exe")

//Give the path of the Firefox Browser        
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

new release https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases