# connection refused when running selenium tests in marionette

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette, geckodriver

I have selenium 2.53.1 tests running on the marionette web driver, I get the following error when running the tests. I have the geckodriver executable installed at /opt/

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The driver server has unexpectedly died!
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'or1010050252127.corp.test.com', ip: '10.50.252.127', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-74-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: MarionetteDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:7048 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Selenium 2.53.1 and Firefox 48 - it turned out that they are not playing well with each other and I had to revert to Firefox 47 - it worked well there.

Marionette/Geckodriver will be used by default in Selenium 3 (still in beta, requires Java 8), in Selenium 2 you have to explicitly request it's usage - by default Selenium uses internal Firefox driver, not compatible with Firefox 48. See [c# Selenium 2.53 moving to marionette driver after firefox upgrade to 47](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761080/c-sharp-selenium-2-53-moving-to-marionette-driver-after-firefox-upgrade-to-47) for details of enabling Marionette.

Additionally, Marionette and Geckodriver are not yet complete ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver/status) is the current status), so it may contain bugs and/or not have the features you need.